# element of array destroy params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have found in my project this piece of code:

```
Project.all.each do |pr|
        if !pr.active
            pr.destroy(nil)
        end
    end
```

What does de `nil` in `pr.destroy(nil)` means?

Comment: Rails' [`destroy`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-destroy) method doesn't seem to take an argument and passing one would raise an `ArgumentError`. Maybe it was replaced by a custom method in your codebase. Try `pr.method(:destroy)` – it should reveal its origin.

Comment: Thank you for that one, didn´t knew about that command, that was an overrided method and yes there is a parameter there